Limit of a characteristic function of a semi open interval given by a convergent sequence
Let $\left(x_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to $x_0$ and $\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}$ the characteristic function of the semi open interval $(-\infty,x_n]$. How would we go about proving that $\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]} \rightarrow \chi_{(-\infty, x_0)}$?
I have tried proving it that $\forall \varepsilon >0 $ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}(x_0 - \varepsilon) = 1$ and equivalently with $\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}(x_0 + \varepsilon) =0$, but i cant really make sense of it if $\left(x_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ isn't monotnically non increasing or non decreasing, or at least bounded above or below by $x_0$. How can i go about finishing this?
Edit: after thinking about it a little more i did find that it could be the case that $\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]} \rightarrow \chi_{(-\infty, x_0]}$, instead of $\chi_{(-\infty, x_0)}$ as in my original question, but for my intents and purposes it will suffice to prove that $\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]} \rightarrow \chi_{(-\infty, x_0]}$ almost everywhere

"I have tried proving [...], but I cant really make sense of it if [...] How can I go about finishing this?": please edit your post to include the details of this attempt.

Let $x_n=-\frac 1  n$ for $n$ odd and $x_n=\frac  1n$ for $n$ even.Then $\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}(0)$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$ so the sequence is not even convergent.
However,$\chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}(x) \rightarrow \chi_{(-\infty, x_0]}(x)$  for $x\neq x_0$. In fact you get eventually  constant sequences both for $x<x_0$ and for $x >x_0$.
[I can add more details if asked for].

Thank you,  proving that χ(−∞,xn]  is pointwise convergent (and is a much more natural argument, and it wasnt hard to convince myself that it would be the case that these sequences are eventually constant
